# Меняющийся коэффициент вероятности

Tags: c#, алгоритм, циклы

Есть некий результат, для достижения которого нужно выполнить последовательно n шагов. Каждый шаг имеет статический и оригинальный коэффициент успеха, известный заранее(в случае неудачи - переходим в начальную точку). Вопрос, как описать в функции хотя 20 таких шагов? Если бы вероятность каждого шага была бы одинаковой, то код выглядел бы примерно так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int countOfIteration = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int count = 1;
        double baseValue = 100;
        double baseRate = 0.66;


        for (int x = 1; x <= countOfIteration; x++)
        {
            if (count > countOfIteration)
            {
                return;
            }
            baseValue = baseValue*baseRate;
            count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(baseValue);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Если вероятности просто заданы априори, то в чем проблема задать массив нужных вероятностей, и на каждом шаге брать оттуда нужное значение? Если же они вычисляются по какой-то формуле, то можете использовать функцию, вычисляющую нужное значение для заданного шага.

Answer (score 2):

Пусть у нас вероятность успеха первого шага 0.5, а вероятность успеха следующего шага втрое меньше.

Тогда пишем как-то так:

```
Random random = new Random();
var currStepSuccessProbability = 0.5;
for (int i = 1; ; i++)
{
    PerformStep(i);
    bool currentStepSucceeded = random.NextDouble() < currStepSuccessProbability;
    if (currentStepSucceeded)
        break;
    currStepSuccessProbability /= 3;
}
```

Для других распределений вероятностей — аналогично.

Comment: а если вероятности будут например 0.69/0.87/0.15/0.43, т.е. будут меняться относительно предыдущего шага бессистемно. мне кажется идея человека, оставившего первый комментарий, верна. т.е. имеем массив с вероятностями для каждого шага и при получении кол-ва шагов перемножаем последовательно на все члены массива, вплоть до члена, чей (индекс+1) равен кол-во итераций.

Comment: @cruim: Ну массив так массив, в чём разница? `currStepSuccessProbability = array[i]`, вот и всё.